# Pointer static method that points to no static method

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've been trying to make a pointer function that points to a method doing something like this(visual C++):

```
struct test
{
  int tst(int a)
  {
    return a * 4;
  }
};
// ok, this the visual C++ compiler does not accept it... (mingw accept it)

int(*tstptr)(int) = (int(*)(int))&test::tst;
```

Then I've done something like this:

```
struct Dx
{
    int SomeMethod()
    {
        return 4;
    }
};

struct Dy
{
    static int(*pSomeMethod)();    
};

int(Dy::*pSomeMethod)() = (int( Dy::*)())&Dx::SomeMethod;
```

So far so good, this compiles without problems, but if I try call her:

```
Dy::pSomeMethod();
```

The compiler returns me:

> Error 1 error LNK2001: external symbol "public: static int (__stdcall
>   * Dy::pSomeMethod) (void)" (? PSomeMethod@Dy@@2P6GHXZA) unresolved

which I do not understand, because  it is not suppose `pSomeMethod` he is not pointing at `SomeMethod` ?

Comment: You do not understand the fundamental difference between a function pointer and a class method pointer. They are two completely different things, and you cannot convert between the two. Neither can you convert a class method pointer of one class into a class method pointer of a different class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `&test::tst` is `int (test::*) (int)`, which is **a member function pointer**.

You are trying to convert it to a **regular** pointer type, which is not possible because they are completely different.

That's why you will have this **type cast** error:

```
error C2440: 'type cast' : 
cannot convert from 'int (__thiscall test::* )(int)' to 'int (__cdecl *)(int)'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int(Dy::*pSomeMethod)() = (int( Dy::*)())&Dx::SomeMethod;
```

Type Checked, so no complain from compiler.

As for:

```
Dy::pSomeMethod();
```

This a __cdecl.
But, SomeMethod is a __thiscall, which means it's really like this

```
int SomeMethod( Dx &this);
```

So， linker can't find a match.

You simply can't call non-static method without object of class Dx.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration of `pSomeMethod` defines a pointer to a function within class `Dy` that returns an `int`.  You want to declare it as it appears in the linker error:

```
int (*Dy::pSomeMethod)();
```

which is a member of `Dy` that is a pointer to a function returning an `int`.

What you're trying to do won't work, since `Dx::SomeMethod` is a member function of `Dx`, which needs a `this` pointer.  Calling thru `pSomeMethod` won't have one.

When done right, you can just assign the address of the function to the pointer without using a cast.